# How do I execute several Tasks and collect their output?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am trying to run several webservices in parallel and collect their results into a single container. I am having a difficult time figuring out the correct syntax.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Rate>> GetRates(Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress,Package package)
{
    var rates = new List<Rate>();
    var tasks = Carriers.Where(carrier => carrier.Enabled)
        .Select(async carrier => 
        {
            try
            {
                rates = await carrier.GetRates(originAddress, destinationAddress, package);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        });

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return rates;
}
```

Comment: Use rates.AddRange(await carrier.GetRates.....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Rate>> GetRates(Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress,Package package)
{
    var rates = new List<Rate>();
    var tasks = Carriers.Where(carrier => carrier.Enabled)
        .Select(async carrier => 
        {
            try
            {
                return carrier.GetRates(originAddress, destinationAddress, package);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        });

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
            foreach (var item in tasks)
            {
                rates.AddRange(item.Result);
            }
    return rates;
}
```

The other way is to add the list from GetRates to a ConcurrentBag. Test both and see which one is faster for yourself ;-)

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetRates()
    {
        var rates = new ConcurrentBag<Rate>();
        var tasks = rates.Where(carrier => carrier.Enabled)
            .Select(async carrier =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var t = await Task.Run(() => carrier.GetRates...
                        foreach (var item in t)
                        {
                            rates.Add(item);
                        }
                    });

                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }); 

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return rates;
    }
```

And yet another solution, based on the solution from felix-b. Well I liked it so much that I decided to have it as an extension method. The extension looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> AsItCompletes<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> taskList)
        {
            var tasks = taskList.ToList();
            var sources = tasks.Select(x => new TaskCompletionSource<T>()).ToList();

            int currentIndex = -1;
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                task.ContinueWith(completed =>
                {
                    var next = sources[Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex)];
                    if (completed.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        next.SetException(completed.Exception);
                    }
                    else if (completed.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        next.SetCanceled();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        next.SetResult(completed.Result);
                    }
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            }

            return sources.Select(source => source.Task);
        }
```

The resulting code, which is more compact and easy to read (no double await, no removing):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Rate>> GetRates(
    Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress, Package package)
{
    List<Task<Rate[]>> mappedTasks = Carriers
        .Where(c => c.Enabled)
        .Select(carrier => ProcessOneCarrier(
            carrier, originAddress, destinationAddress, package))
        .ToList();

    List<Rate> reducedResults = new List<Rate>();

    foreach (var task in mappedTasks.AsItCompletes())
    {
        Rate[] rates = await task;
        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            // Handle Exception
        }
        reducedResults.AddRange(rates);           
    }

    return reducedResults;
}

async Task<Rate[]> ProcessOneCarrier(
    Carrier carrier, Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress, Package package)
{
    var rates = await carrier.GetRates(originAddress, destinationAddress, package);
    return rates.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Great answer!  I have one question though.  As each task is completed, I want to catch any exceptions and proceed executing the others.  Is this simply a matter of surrounding the foreach block with a try...catch block? The SetException is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Nope. After the await check if task.Exception has a value. I should have added it to the example. Something like if (task.Exception != null) do something

Comment: So I will create an AggregateAcception add any task exceptions  to it.  If the AggregateException has exceptions when the tasks are done, then throw it?

Comment: I dont think you need an AggregateException at all. If the task failes, the exception thrown will be on task.Exception. How you handle it is up to you and depends on what happens... I've added a snippet for exception handling

Comment: I may not need it, but if the all the carriers throw exceptions, I want to return it to the caller in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more efficient solution that doesn't require locking (`ConcurrentBag` is unnecessary):

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Rate>> GetRates(
    Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress, Package package)
{
    List<Task<Rate[]>> mappedTasks = Carriers
        .Where(c => c.Enabled)
        .Select(carrier => ProcessOneCarrier(
            carrier, originAddress, destinationAddress, package))
        .ToList();

    List<Rate> reducedResults = new List<Rate>();

    while (mappedTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(mappedTasks);
        Rate[] rates = await finishedTask;
        reducedResults.AddRange(rates);
        mappedTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }

    return reducedResults;
}

async Task<Rate[]> ProcessOneCarrier(
    Carrier carrier, Address originAddress, Address destinationAddress, Package package)
{
    var rates = await carrier.GetRates(originAddress, destinationAddress, package);
    return rates.ToArray();
}
```

Based on [Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) sample.

Comment: yep. Better solution